# IOS Custom Keyboard Suggestions with UITextChecker

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard

Here i reached so far. I have a function that receive a string and showing me some suggestions for my custom keyboard.

-(void)suggestionsForCustomKeyboard:(NSString *)word{

```
NSArray *arrPredectiveText;
UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, word.length);
arrPredectiveText = [checker completionsForPartialWordRange:searchRange inString:word language:currentLanguage];

NSArray *guesses = [NSArray array];

if ([currentString length] >= 1) {

    UITextChecker *textChecker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSRange misspelledRange = [textChecker
                               rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:currentString
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])
                               startingAt:0
                               wrap:NO
                               language:@"en_US"];


    if (misspelledRange.location != NSNotFound) {

        guesses = [textChecker guessesForWordRange:misspelledRange
                                          inString:currentString
                                          language:@"en_US"];
        NSLog(@"First guess: %@", [guesses firstObject]);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Textchecker Not found");
        autocorrectedText = @"";
    }

    if (arrPredectiveText.count >= 2){
        suggestionOne = [arrPredectiveText objectAtIndex:0];
        suggestionTwo = [arrPredectiveText objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else if (arrPredectiveText.count == 1 && guesses.count >= 1) {
        suggestionOne = [arrPredectiveText firstObject];
        suggestionTwo = [guesses firstObject];
    }else if (arrPredectiveText.count == 0 && guesses.count > 0){
        suggestionOne = [guesses firstObject];
        if (guesses.count > 1) {
            suggestionTwo = [guesses objectAtIndex:1];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Textchecker all guess: %@", guesses);
    NSLog(@"Prediction: %@",arrPredectiveText);
```

}

The last two lines are the print statement for two types. One is for guesses words when misspelled occurred and the other is for dictionary words. 
The arrPredectiveText array contains words sequentially like dictionary.

Please give some idea or way to solving the suggestion and next word predict mechanism for ios custom keyboard like other apps. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question and i found a little bit better way for suggestion. This may help others.

// Suggestion Improvement

```
+ (void)getSuggestionsFor:(NSString *)word WithCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *))completion
{
    //    NSLog(@"Current String %@",word);
    NSString *prefix;
    if ([word length] > 1) {
        prefix = [word substringToIndex:word.length - 1];
    }else{
        prefix = [word substringToIndex:word.length];
    }
    // Won't get suggestions for correct words, so we are scrambling the words
    //    NSLog(@"Prefix String %@",prefix);
    NSString *scrambledWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",word, [self getRandomCharAsNSString]];
    //    NSLog(@"scrambledWord String %@",scrambledWord);
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSRange checkRange = NSMakeRange(0, scrambledWord.length);
    NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:scrambledWord range:checkRange startingAt:checkRange.location wrap:YES  language:@"en_US"];

    NSArray *arrGuessed = [checker guessesForWordRange:misspelledRange inString:scrambledWord language:@"en_US"];
    //    NSLog(@"Guess Arr ===== %@",arrGuessed);
    // Filter the result based on the word
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",word];
    NSArray *arrayfiltered = [arrGuessed filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    //    NSLog(@"1 arrayfiltered character %@",arrayfiltered);
    if(arrayfiltered.count == 0)
    {
        // Filter the result based on the prefix
        NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",prefix];
        arrayfiltered = [arrGuessed filteredArrayUsingPredicate:newPredicate];
        //        NSLog(@"2 arrayfiltered character %@",arrayfiltered);
    }
    if (arrayfiltered.count == 0) {

        NSArray *arrPredectiveText;
        UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
        NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
        NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, word.length);
        arrPredectiveText = [checker completionsForPartialWordRange:searchRange inString:word language:currentLanguage];
        //        NSLog(@"3 arrayfiltered character %@",arrPredectiveText);

        if (arrPredectiveText.count == 0 && arrGuessed.count != 0) {
            completion(arrGuessed);
        }else{
            completion(arrPredectiveText);
        }
    }else{
        completion(arrayfiltered);
    }
}

+ (NSString *)getRandomCharAsNSString{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a'];
    //    NSLog(@"Random character %@",str);
    return str;
}
```

By calling this getSuggestionsFor... block with a input string you will get good suggestions in block completion as an array of suggested string.